# Javascript formatting of 10 or 11 digit phone numbers and recognizing a 1800 phone number

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get javascript to format phone numbers based on a users input of 10 or 11 digits. The 11 digits are for phone numbers that start with a 1 at the beginning like a 1-800 number. I need the final output to be either 000-000-0000 or 1-000-000-0000. The sample javascript code that I was given to start out with, works with the 10 digit phone number but I need the javascript to also recognize if there is a 1800 number and append accordingly.

The following is my initial working javascript and below that is code I found online that addresses the 10 and 11 digital formatting however I don’t know how to mesh the two together.

Thank you in advance for any help given.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var phoneNumberVars = [ "UserProfilePhone", "UserProfilePhone1", "UserProfilePhone2", "UserProfilePhone3",  ];

InitialFormatTelephone();

function InitialFormatTelephone()
{
  for (var i = 0; i < phoneNumberVars.length; i++)
  {
    FormatTelephone(phoneNumberVars[i]);
  }
}

function StorefrontEvaluateFieldsHook(field)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < phoneNumberVars.length; i++)
  {
    if (field.id == "FIELD_" + FieldIDs[phoneNumberVars[i]])
    {
      FormatTelephone(phoneNumberVars[i]);
    }
  }
}

function FormatTelephone(varName)
{
  var num = document.getElementById("FIELD_" + FieldIDs[varName]).value;
  var charArray = num.split("");
  var digitCounter = 0;
  var formattedNum;
  if (charArray.length > 0)
   formattedNum = “-“;
  else
   formattedNum = "";

  var i;

  for (i = 0;i < charArray.length; i++)
  {
    if (isDigit(charArray[i]))
    {
      formattedNum = formattedNum + charArray[i];
      digitCounter++;
      if (digitCounter == 3)
      {
        formattedNum = formattedNum + “-“;
      }
      if (digitCounter == 6)
      {
        formattedNum = formattedNum + "-";
      }
    }
  }
  if (digitCounter != 0 && digitCounter != 10)
  {
    alert ("Enter a valid phone number!");
  }
  // now that we have a formatted version of the user's phone number, replace the field with this new value
  document.getElementById("FIELD_" + FieldIDs[varName]).value = formattedNum;

  // force an update of the preview
  PFSF_AjaxUpdateForm();
}

function isDigit(aChar)
{
  myCharCode = aChar.charCodeAt(0);
  if((myCharCode > 47) && (myCharCode <  58))
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great questions tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: I believe, after reading the "How to Ask" page, that I have probably added to much code to my question. However, I am not a javascript writer and I don't know what the least amount of information from the program to be pertinent in solving this would be. I am only familiar with how to change the "(", ")" and "-" in the code. I understand if I have added to much information for this to be easily solved. Thank you for your response.

Comment: you could try to reduce the question issue to an [mcve] at least..

Comment: Hi Ochi, I was able to get an outside developer to work on it for me and its now working. I can't explain what changes have been made but the following code works. Hopefully this helps the next person needing this info.

Comment: You could try adding it as an answer for the next person :)

Comment: you probly want regexes rather

Comment: I was also trying to delete that second set of code in my original question. It doesn't pertain to any of it now. Do you know how to delete or can you delete the code the starts with /* FORMAT PHONE BEHAVIOR MASK */

Comment: you can use the edit button to modify any part of your question

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var phoneNumberVars = [ "UserProfilePhone", "UserProfilePhone1",   "UserProfilePhone2", "UserProfilePhone3",  ];

InitialFormatTelephone();

    function InitialFormatTelephone()
{
  for (var i = 0; i < phoneNumberVars.length; i++)
  {
    FormatTelephone(phoneNumberVars[i]);
  }
}

function StorefrontEvaluateFieldsHook(field)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < phoneNumberVars.length; i++)
  {
    if (field.id == "FIELD_" + FieldIDs[phoneNumberVars[i]])
    {
      FormatTelephone(phoneNumberVars[i]);
    }
  }
}

function FormatTelephone(varName)
{
  var num = document.getElementById("FIELD_" + FieldIDs[varName]).value;
  var cleanednum = num.replace( /[^0-9]/g, "");
  var charArray = cleanednum.split("");

  var digitCounter = 0;

var formattedNum = "";

var digitPos1 = 0;
var digitPos3 = 3;
var digitPos6 = 6;

  if (charArray.length ===11)
  {
        digitPos1++;
        digitPos3++;
        digitPos6++;
        }

  if (charArray.length > 0)
   formattedNum = "";
  else
   formattedNum = "";

  var i;
  for (i = 0;i < charArray.length; i++)
  {
    if (isDigit(charArray[i]))
    {
      formattedNum = formattedNum + charArray[i];
      digitCounter++;


      if (digitCounter === digitPos1)
      {
            formattedNum = formattedNum + "-";
            }
      if (digitCounter == digitPos3)
      {
            formattedNum = formattedNum + "-";
            }
          if (digitCounter == digitPos6)
      {
            formattedNum = formattedNum + "-";
            }
    }
  }

  if ((charArray.length ==10 || charArray.length == 11 || charArray.length == 0) === false)

  {
    alert ("Enter a valid phone number!");
    }
  // now that we have a formatted version of the user's phone number, replace the field with this new value
  document.getElementById("FIELD_" + FieldIDs[varName]).value = formattedNum;

  // force an update of the preview
  PFSF_AjaxUpdateForm();
}

function isDigit(aChar)
{
  myCharCode = aChar.charCodeAt(0);
  if((myCharCode > 47) && (myCharCode <  58))
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
</script>
```